# How are we going to deal with Qt 5.0 questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Now that [Qt 5.0 is released](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/12/19/qt-5-0/), we can expect to see a number of questions popping up on the site relating to the new release.

We already have a tag: [qt5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qt5)

So my question is thus: are we going to merge the [qt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qt) and [qt5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qt5) tags or do we really need to keep them separate?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say keep them separate - at least for now. We have versioning for many tags, to keep the questions - and more importantly, the sollutions - apart.

I think this is very helpful, especially in regards to APIs and considerably new versions, as it may or may not be consistent through the versions.

**Merge 4 to 6 months after release**, perhaps?

Comment: I agree.  Don't merge them for 4-6 months.  +1.